# Saben porque Pypy no me deja instalar matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, cython

Tengo un problema al instalar matplotlib en pypy3 verifique por si lo tenia instalado por defecto pero al parecer no, tengo todas las dependencia de microsoft visual studio c++ instalada pero aun así no me deja instalar el modulo de matplotlib tendrán idea de que podrá ser? De antemano Gracias
[image]

Comment: Pon el mensaje que arroja _como texto, con formato_. La imagen es prácticamente ilegible.

Comment: De mano, se ve en el mensaje que hay un error durante la compilación. Matplotlib es una extensión escrita en su mayor parte en C, y la instalación está intentando compilarla. El compilador da error. Quizás es que tu compilador no es gcc. De cualquier forma es posible que tengas muchos problemas tratando de hacer esto, pues pypy es una implementación del intérprete escrita en Python, en vez de en C, por lo que no tengo claro si será capaz de aceptar extensiones hechas en C como matplotlib.